# How to create a Generic Dictionary?

Tags: c#, generic-programming

I have a Class where i have a Dictionary holding a specific Key. But the Value should be generic.

Something like:

```
private Dictionary<String,TValue> _Dictionary;
```

But TValue is not found (obvesly) but what else should i put in? I found a solution for IList but i just want to add **one** Generic Object.

Comment: Where is this going to be used?

Answer (score 2):

So you want a generic dictionary? Use the pre defined class.

```
public Dictionary<int, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

That gives you a dictionary with an integer key, and a string value. If you need a Dictionary with only one of those being variable, you can inherit Dictionary to make your own type.

```
public class KeyTypeConstantDictionary<T> : Dictionary<int, T>
{
}
```

Then using it is like so:

```
KeyTypeConstantDictionary<string> x = new KeyTypeConstantDictonary<string>();
// Equivalent to Dictionary<int, string>()
KeyTypeConstantDictionary<SomeObject> x = new KeyTypeConstantDictonary<SomeObject>();
// Equivalent to Dictionary<int, SomeObject>()
```

Hopefully I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using this within a generic type, [Tejs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331602/how-to-create-a-generic-dictionary/5331651#5331651) is appropriate.

However, if you're just trying to make a dictionary with a fixed type of key, but which can store any value, one option is to just use `System.Object` for your value:

```
 private Dictionary<string, object> _dictionary;
```

This will allow you to assign any object into the value.  However, this is potentially dangerous, as you lose type safety and need to make sure to unbox and convert the object correctly.

Comment: Plus, going the object type for the value doesnt make it much better than a System.Collections.Hashtable! =D

Comment: @Tejs: It depends on what your goal is here - What do you plan to store in the value?  That'd help us determine what the best option actually is...